# unable to predict when all the threads have finished execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code

```
package pe.entel.ftp;

public class Myclass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myclass runnable = new Myclass();
        ThreadGroup tg1 = new ThreadGroup("Parent ThreadGroup");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(tg1, runnable, i + "");
            t1.start();
            System.out.println("Thread Group Name: " + tg1.getName());

        }
        while (tg1.isDestroyed()) {
            System.out.println("yes success");
        }

        System.out.println("completed");

    }
}
```

while my part of o/p is

```
  Thread Group Name: Parent ThreadGroup
  Thread Group Name: Parent ThreadGroup
  Thread Group Name: Parent ThreadGroup
  Thread Group Name: Parent ThreadGroup
  Thread Group Name: Parent ThreadGroup
 completed
 84 
 86
 88
 90
 92
 94
 96
 98
 95
 97
 99
```

Here I am unable to predict when exactly thread group is completing execution.Even ,while loop for checking whether thread group is destroyed is also not working.Even after printing completed some threads are executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ThreadGroup does not complete execution. If you want to wait for all threads to finish, you have to collect them and wait for all of them:

```
List<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  Thread t1 = new Thread(tg1, runnable, i + "");
        t1.start();
   allThreads.add(t1);  
}

allThreads.forEach(Thread::join);
```

ThreadGroups exist longer than the threads they contain, you might want to add new threads to a ThreadGroup after all the threads up to now have finished. They are merely grouping threads, not controlling them.

Comment: I want to execute all the threads at once.For the code you have given.Threads will execute one after other because of join.

Comment: No. The threads are started in the for loop with `t1.start()`command and run in parallel. What is done sequentially, is the join, that is the waiting on the thread's end. You wait for the first thread to have finished with `join()`. When this happens, you wait for the finishing of the second thread. If this was faster than the first thread, `join()`returns immediately, and you'd jump to waiting on the third and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to predict when exactly thread group is completing execution

Another way to do it is to use an `ExecutorService` thread pool instead of forking the threads yourself:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new Myclass());
}
// shutdown the pool after the last runnable has been submitted
threadPool.shutdown();
// wait for all of the jobs to finish
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You can also use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(#)` to only fork a certain number of threads to limit the number of concurrent operations.